# How to interpolate into a rotated grid?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I have

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
 [2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
 [3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
 [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]]
```

and I want to interpolate it into a rotated grid that has a corner on the left edge. Similar to:

```
[[2, ~2, 2],
 [~4, ~4, ~4],
 [6, ~6, 6]]
```

(I use `~` to denote approximate values. )

(Of course, my actual data is more complex. The scenario is that I want to map DEM data by pixel onto a rotated image.)

Here is the setup:

```
import numpy
from scipy import interpolate as interp

grid = numpy.ndarray((5, 5))
for I in range(grid.shape[0]):
    for j in range(grid.shape[1]):
        grid[I, j] = I + j

grid = ndimage.interpolation.shift(
    ndimage.interpolation.rotate(grid, -45, reshape=False),
    -1)

source_x, source_y = numpy.meshgrid(
    numpy.arange(0, 5), numpy.arange(0, 5))
target_x, target_y = numpy.meshgrid(
    numpy.arange(0, 2), numpy.arange(0, 2))

print(interp.griddata(
    numpy.array([source_x.ravel(), source_y.ravel()]).T,
    grid.ravel(),
    target_x, target_y))
```

This is giving me:

```
[[2.4467   2.6868 2.4467]
 [4.       4.     4.    ]
 [5.5553   5.3132 5.5553]]
```

This is promising. However, the rotation and shift values are hard-coded, and I should at least be able to get the upper-left corner exact.

I do know the indices of the corners of the grid I wish to interpolate to. That is, I have

```
upper_left = 2, 0
upper_right = 0, 2
lower_right = 4, 2
lower_left = 2, 4
```

Comment: Does [ndimage.rotate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.rotate.html) do what you want?

Comment: @WelcometoStackOverflow I'm definitely playing with it. I reckon it would have to be paired with some sort of interpolating-translation function, as the new corner would be in the center of the rotated edge. (I'm vaguely worried about losing data in the rotation, but not sure how much that matters in practice.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be builtin enough for your taste, but here is a method that uses your starting point (grid corners) more directly, and applies spline interpolation (cubic per default).

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import RectBivariateSpline

# input data
data = np.array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
                 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                 [2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                 [3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
                 [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]])

upper_left = 2, 0
upper_right = 0, 2
lower_right = 2, 4   # note that I swapped this
lower_left = 4, 2    # and this
n_steps = 3, 3


# build interpolator
m, n = data.shape
x, y = np.arange(m), np.arange(n)

interpolator = RectBivariateSpline(x, y, data)

# build grid
ul,ur,ll,lr = map(np.array, (upper_left,upper_right,lower_left,lower_right))
assert np.allclose(ul + lr, ur + ll)    # make sure edges are parallel

x, y = ul[:, None, None] \
       + np.outer(ll-ul, np.linspace(0.0, 1.0, n_steps[0]))[:, :, None] \
       + np.outer(ur-ul, np.linspace(0.0, 1.0, n_steps[1]))[:, None, :]

# intepolate on grid
print(interpolator.ev(x, y))
```

Prints:

```
[[2. 2. 2.]
 [4. 4. 4.]
 [6. 6. 6.]]
```

Comment: Yeah, that's more what I want! I'll award the bounty when I'm allowed, assuming nothing better comes along

Answer (score 0):

While this does answer my question, I hope there is a more built-in way of doing things. I am still seeking a better approach.

---

This is really two problems: rotating the original grid, and then interpolating. Rotating the grid and then translating it to the correct upper-left corner can be done with an [Affine Transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation).

`skimage` provides an [easy function](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.transform.html#skimage.transform.AffineTransform) for this purpose.

```
from skimage.transform import AffineTransform, warp
# Set up grid as in question
transform = AffineTransform(rotation=-math.pi / 4,
                            scale=(math.sqrt(2)/2, math.sqrt(2)/2),
                            translations=(0,2))
grid = warp(grid, transform)
```

The result of this is

```
[[2. 2. 2. 2. 2.]
 [3. 3. 3. 3. 3.]
 [4. 4. 4. 4. 4.]
 [5. 5. 5. 5. 5.]
 [6. 6. 6. 6. 6.]]
```

which may then be simply resampled as desired.

In general, if we have a grid with dimensions x and y, and coordinates p1, p2, p3, p4 (starting from upper-left, going clockwise) we want to rotate to, we have

```
rotation = math.atan2(p4.x - p1.x, p4.y - p1.y)
scale = (math.sqrt((p2.y - p1.y) ** 2 + (p2.x - p1.x) ** 2) / x,
         math.sqrt((p4.y - p1.y) ** 2 + (p4.x - p1.x) ** 2) / y)
translation = (0, p1.y)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "builtin"?  Just plain `numpy`?

Comment: @DanielF Sorry, that was the wrong word. Libraries are fine. I think I meant a more "direct" approach. Its' just that I somewhat expect there to be something to calculate the rotation and scaling arguments for me.